# A neat way to create an infinite cyclic generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want a generator that cycle infinitely through a list of values.

Here is my solution, but I may be missing a more obvious one.

The ingredients: a generator function that flatten an infinitely nested list, and a list appendant to itself

```
def ge(x):
    for it in x:
        if isinstance(it, list):
            yield from ge(it)
        else:
            yield(it)


def infinitecyclegenerator(l):
    x = l[:]
    x.append(x)
    yield from ge(x)
```

The use:

```
g = infinitecyclegenerator([1,2,3])

next(g) #1
next(g) #2
next(g) #3
next(g) #1
next(g) #2
next(g) #3
next(g) #1
...
```

As I said, I may be missing a trivial way to do the same and I'll be happy to learn. Is there a neater way?

Also, should I worry about memory consumption with all the mind boggling infinities going on here, or is everything cool with my code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to achieve the same result

> Make an iterator returning elements from the iterable and saving a
>   copy of each. When the iterable is exhausted, return elements from the
>   **saved copy**.

*Emphasis mine*. Your only concern about memory would be saving a copy of each item returned by the *iterator*.

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> c = cycle([1,2,3])
>>> next(c)
1
>>> next(c)
2
>>> next(c)
3
>>> next(c)
1
>>> next(c)
2
>>> next(c)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be the hour :-). The one obvious way I realized after posting:

```
def infinitecyclegenerator(l):
    while True:
        for it in l:
            yield it
```

Sorry for missing the obvious.